# Can I get user password from Wordpress database for React application?

Tags: javascript, sql, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

Im wondering if this is a good idea or even possible as I cant find an example...

Im attempting to create a React application(using Postgres) inside Wordpress(using MySql) because Wordpress has so much stuff built in for nice theming, posts, and especially user management accounts.  However, for each user can I get the Wordpress password and save it in another database the React application is using so as to connect the two?

Follow-up: I can probably use the REST API but that password is likely salted right?  Wondering what problems I'll run into before undertaking this endeavor...

Comment: Unless you are using the same hashing function, on the same machine, as before, you are going to get different results

Comment: @Luca is there an intermediate solution?

Comment: An intermediate between Wordpress and React? I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy passwords into second (any) database (or many microservices).

It depends what you need, there are many scenarios.

You can use WP authorization to access second DB. Simplest ... you can extend WP REST API with functions operating on Postgres. React/client won't see any difference - you can change backend 'behind scene' w/o any client change - as long as your API will be the same.

If your app will be bigger (and independent) you can use other methods like tokens, 3rd party authorization.